# Grails loop with fieldValue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I know how to use `fieldValue()` in a template.gsp using a `g:each` tag. But how can you use it if you were looping through returned database info in a controller?

```
def retObj=[];
for( x in returnedFromDataBase){
    var current=retObj.push([:]);
    //how do I make this get the value of the current row using fieldValue??
    current.myname=fieldValue(bean:returnedFromDataBase, field: "name")
}
```

Comment: the fieldValue() is supposed to have better sql injection protection??

Comment: fieldValue defend you from XSS injections. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting